# tour.golang.org#36 The functionality implemented by pic.Show

Tags: go

In [tour.golang.org , exercice 36](http://tour.golang.org/moretypes/14) , what this statement `pic.Show(Pic)` supposed to do?

```
package main

import "code.google.com/p/go-tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    var p = make([]([]uint8), dy)
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        p[i] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for j := 0; j < len(p[i]); j++ {
            p[i][j] = uint8((i + j) / 2)
        }
    }
    return p
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

when I run the example, it just print some characters on the standard output, isn’t supposed to show some picture?

Comment: Works for me. It's showing an image with a gradient.

Comment: @eminor show me the code please

Comment: I just copied your code and pressed the run button.

Comment: Screenshot: http://imgur.com/00T3bx0

Comment: @eminor , I get it now, I was running the example locally `go run 36.go` :)

Comment: I had the same behaviour; I don't know why but when I import "fmt" then I get a printed out text representing the image (pretty sure it's the base 64 encoded png because I can get chrome to print it out by prefixing with "data:image/png;base64," :D ) - if I remove the "fmt" import and any uses then it displays the picture. Some unexpected interaction there I guess.

Comment: Maybe your code should leverage the range syntax insteaf of the classical for in order to fit better the go tour context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pic.Show()` creates the image and encodes it as base64. Here is the code:

```
func Show(f func(int, int) [][]uint8) {
        const (
                dx = 256
                dy = 256
        )
        data := f(dx, dy)
        m := image.NewNRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, dx, dy))
        for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
                for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
                        v := data[y][x]
                        i := y*m.Stride + x*4
                        m.Pix[i] = v
                        m.Pix[i+1] = v
                        m.Pix[i+2] = 255
                        m.Pix[i+3] = 255
                }
        }
        ShowImage(m)
}

func ShowImage(m image.Image) {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        err := png.Encode(&buf, m)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        enc := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf.Bytes())
        fmt.Println("IMAGE:" + enc)
}
```

Funny thing is it ends up printing the string "IMAGE:" followed by the base64 encoded string. Seems that play.golang.org parses the output converting this to an `img` tag. Try the following example: http://play.golang.org/p/RZPqp164eS